# Threads reactor-http-nio compute something for a long time and consume CPU and memory

Tags: project-reactor, reactor-netty

We have a service to which we connect via websocket and receive messages from it. We have updated dependencies for Spring Boot 3.0.6, reactor: 1.1.6, reactor-core 3.5.5 services.

After connecting to the service via websocket, threads named reactor-http-nio start consuming CPU and memory. And after some time, Kubernetes kills the pod with the error Exit Code: 137 (Exit Code 137 errors happen when a container or pod was terminated due to high memory usage) and creates a new one (and so many times).

In the local version, after several such connections, it is no longer possible to make new connections to the service. If we wait 10-15 minutes, then the load from these threads will disappear and we can connect again. There are no errors in the logs of the service itself.

Here are screenshots with information about the state of the CPU and threads before the test, in which a websocket connection takes place:

- [CPU before test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPe6d.png)
- [Threads before test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGvxQ.png)

And after:

- [CPU after test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3DgC.png)
- [Threads after test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ExqQ.png)
- [The content of one of the threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMI4x.png)

I did as it is written in the instructions here:

- https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#faq.memory-leaks
- https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Reference-counted-objects#troubleshooting-buffer-leaks

But nothing showed up in the logs either.

Please tell me how can I understand the cause of this problem.

UPDATE 1:

I also found out that the project has @ReactiveFeignClient from the PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive (v4.0.0) library.
When @ReactiveFeignClient send requests during the tests, then it is these streams (which are on the screenshots) that are loaded.
But PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive works through project-reactor.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the FluxZip handling of the SimpleReactiveRetryPolicy and RetryPublisherHttpClient. This is a bug in PlatikaOSS feign-reactive introduced with reactor v3.4.25.

Check this out for more

https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive/issues/590#issuecomment-1597496587

Update: use feign-reactor v 4.0.3

Comment: Yes thanks, I'm watching this issue.